# Extract links from mysql and make it clickable?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have a database table that stores URL.What I need is grab those URL's from table and make it click-able with the URL's title as anchor.

This is what I have tried:

```
while($row4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result4))
{
   echo "<a href =\"$row4[Url1]\">".$row4['Title1']. "</a>";
}
```

It displays for example my `tilte1` that is `youtube` and `Url1` is `www.youtube.com`.

But when I click on it it is going to `localhost/mysite/www.youtube.com`

How can I fix this?

Comment: please put `http://` in your database before  `www.youtube.com`

Comment: make changes in your 
example my `tilte1` that is `youtube` and `Url1` is `http://www.youtube.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `http://` in front of the link. Then it will go to where you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
echo "<a href =\"http://$row4[Url1]\">".$row4['Title1']. "</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

you need http:// in front.

```
echo '<a href ="http://'.$row4['Url1'].'">'.$row4['Title1']. '</a>';
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo How does it not provide answer to the question? You mean what if link is https or ftp, or something 3rd?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if your Url1 field is a proper url? see if it has http:// protocol in the url. if not you will need to add it to prepend it to your table or programmatically prepend http:// protocol to your link.

Additionally you can use below function taken form codeigniter framework. It prepares your link for url.  do prep_url($row4[Url1]) instead of just $row4[Url1];

```
function prep_url($str = '')
{
  if ($str == 'http://' OR $str == '')
  {
    return '';
  }
  $url = parse_url($str);
  if ( ! $url OR ! isset($url['scheme']))
  {
    $str = 'http://'.$str;
  }
  return $str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
while($row4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result4))
{
   echo "<a href ='http://".$row4['Url1']."'>".$row4['Title1']. "</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make an absolute link from that, and don't forget to put  attributes' values in quotes.
I suggest this:

```
echo '<a href="http://www.'.$row4[Url1].'">'.$row4['Title1']. '</a>';
//by doing this you also won't need any of \ slashes
```

Answer (score 0):

I enter urls enclosed in quotes, example:
"http://google.com"
Then I use:

.$row['date']."< a href=".$row['title'].">".$row['title']."< /a>
".

the result is a clickable link in the form of:
 http://google.com
remove the space between < and a, ( i had to add a space for the code to post.